# Catch error and ask for manual input in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I  have the following code:

```
if [ -e /etc/my.cnf ]; then
    _out_fn="/etc/my.cnf"
        if [ ! -e ${_out_fn}_orig ] ; then
        cp $_out_fn ${_out_fn}_orig
        fi
    cp /dev/null $_out_fn
    while read line ; do
    set -- $line
        if [ "$1" = "[mysqld]" ] ; then
            echo $line >> $_out_fn
            line="safe-show-database
            skip-networking
            local-infile=0
            symbolic-links=0"
        fi
    echo $line >> $_out_fn
    done < ${_out_fn}_orig
    echo "$MySQL Securing Complete! "
else
    echo "$MySQL Configuration File Not Found! "
fi
```

Is there a way to have the option for the code to ask for a manual location in case of failure?

Comment: Most likely, but in case of failure of what?

Comment: There is already an else clause in your code.. Ask for a input location if my.cnf resides on some other place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `read`. The snippet that asks for a manual input could look like this:

```
config_location=
while : ; do
        echo -n "Enter the path to the configuration file: "
        read config_location
        if test -r "$config_location"; then
                break
        fi
        echo "File $config_location not found or is unreadable, let's try again."
done
echo "OK, $config_location exists."
```

Here we continue asking the user until the path he provides exists and is readable (`test -r`). The `while : ; do` is an endless loop. If you only need to ask for the path once, you only need this:

```
echo -n "Enter the path to the configuration file: "
read config_location
```

Comment: Or `while ! -r "$config_location"; do ...`